# What does this E100 timestamp by Schlumberger Eclipse mean?

Tags: timestamp, simulation, timestamp-analysis

I am doing analysis on a reservoir where I have the following YEAR and TIME. The data is imported according to the E100 black oil model from the Eclipse software (Schlumberger) -- this Eclipse is not the same as the traditional Eclipse used for software development, it is the software used by petroleum engineers. I know the timestamp is around the years 1988-2005, probably close to 15.06.1992-15.09.1999 (timestamps in other reservoir). I am not sure whether the timestamps are corrupted or whether this kind of timestamp really exist where some years oddly are zero between measurements.

**What do the timestamps mean here expressed in the YEAR part and the TIME part?**

[image]

Comment: The manufacturer of the software has their documentation behind a paywall. Do you have any examples of known timestamps from another source? Any more information about the file itself? (Extension, creation date, etc) Do you know what the sampling interval was, so we can try to work backwards? It doesn't look to be in any epoch format, but the time field looks a lot like it could be a Julian day number.